# Passing parameters from shell to awk as an array

Tags: shell, awk

I am using a shell script and within that I am using an awk script. I am passing parameters to `awk` from shell script by using `-v` option. At some point of time, when the argument size exceeds a certain limit, I was getting the 'Argument list too long error'. This was my previous question but I have found out the root cause for the same.  Now my question is:

> Variable to be passed from shell to awk using -v option = too large ⟶ Hence getting argument list too long error

My idea is to break the large variable into small chunks and store it in an array and then pass the array into `awk` instead of passing the single variable into `awk`.

My question is:

- Is it possible to break the large variable into small array and then pass it back to `awk`. I know how to modify a variable of shell inside an `awk` script. But how can I modify the array of shell inside an `awk` script?

I read that -v option is not advisable and they suggested to pipe the variable values. So if that the case

```
echo variable | awk '{}'
```

So variables would be piped. But I have to pipe an array along with some other variables. Could you  please help me?

```
 CODE DESCRIPTION
 addvariable=""
 export variable
 loop begins
 eval $(awk -v tempvariable="$addvariable" '{tempvariable=tempvariable+"long string"  variable=tempvariable(Here is where the shell variable(variable) is being modified )}')

  In shell
  addvariable=$variable (Taking the new value of shell variable and feeding back to awk in the next iteration)
   loop ends
```

So the problem is now as the addvariable and variable keeps on increasing, I am get argument too long error .. So what I have to do is to split the tempvariable into small chunks and then store it in variable[1] variable[2] etc and then assign that to addvariable[1], addvariable[2] and the feed addvariable[1],[2] instead of feeding the entire addvariable as a whole.So my question is how to feed that as an array. and how to store the big data inside the awk into variable[1] variable[2]

CODE
    addshellvariable=""

```
for i in {0..10}
{
zcat normalfile{i} > FILE A
zcat hugefile{i} > FILE

export shellvariable=""
getdate=grep "XXX" FILE B|sort|Uniq (getdate contains a list of id's)
eval $(awk -v getdata="$getdata" -v addshellvariable="$addshellvariable" BEGIN {tempvariable="";split(addshellvariable,tempshellvariableArray,"*");while(t <= length(tempshellvariable)) {awkarray[tempshellvariableArray[t]];} {for(id in ids) {awkarray[id];} END {for(id in awkarray) {tempvariable=tempvariable"*"id"*"awkarray[id]}  **print "shellvariable"=tempvariable;**}} FILE A)

  addshellvariable=$shellvariable;
}
```

So as you can see awk is being embedded inside the shell . everytime I need the awkarray content to be feedback into the awk again .. So that I will be able to get the updated ones and that is the reason I am getting the awk array content in the shell variable by printing that, again the shell variable is stored in an another shell variable "addshellvariable" and that is being given to the awk in the next iteration. But the problem is when the shellvariable size increases a certain point then I am getting an Argument too long error . Thus I wanted a solution in such a way that , instead of doing
**print "shellvariable"=tempvariable;** I can make it as **print "shellvariable[1]"=A part of tempvariable;** and so on ...

Comment: I think you need to show some code illustrating how you're currently doing it because it is not obvious how you'd be passing a shell array to `awk` via `-v` without flattening the array into a single string.  Your `awk` script cannot directly modify the shell's copy of the shell array.  What is in your array?  Do the elements of the array themselves contain blanks or newlines or other characters that cause trouble?

Comment: Your 'here is where the shell variable is being modified' comment is erroneous if it is part of the `awk` command line.  You simply can't modify the shell variable from within `awk`.  You've not actually shown where the `awk` program appears on the command line.

Comment: I am not modifying the shell variable within awk I am just using eval to take that value.. Sorry I forgot to mention eval

Comment: **Why do you think you need to use eval?**  And can you show us your actual code?  In your question, the line that seems to run awk seems to assign variables badly and doesn't include any input data.  Or is this shell script that is not a shell script intended to take its data from stdin?

Comment: My question is inside awk , the shell variable named "variable" is assigned a huge value and hence shell throws an error stating that the argument list is too high.. For this purpose I need to have the shell variable named "variable" as an array so that inside awk instead of assign the value of the variable directly, I can assign that to an array named variable...

Comment: NandaKumar, I *want* up upvote this question, because it would be a good one if it were expressed properly.  Please do spend a bit more time communicating what you want.  Include your *actual* code, something that people answering can use to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I have given the actual code .. Could you ppl please have a look at the same . Thank you

Comment: Your code is missing two single quotes (at least) to make it a legitimate use of `awk`.  And you need to format that code so it is legible, too.

Answer (score 3):

Your shell appears to have limited you.  I suspect that your guess is correct, and this isn't an awk problem, it's the scripting language from which you're calling awk.

You can pre-load awk with variables loaded from a file.  Check this out:

```
$ printf 'foo=2\nbar=3\nbaz=4\n' > vars
$ printf 'snarf\nblarg\nbaz\nsnurry\n' > text
$ awk 'NR==FNR{split($0,a,"=");vars[a[1]]=a[2];next} $1 in vars {print vars[$1]}' vars text
4
$
```

**How does this work?**

The first two printf lines give us our raw data.  Run them without the redirect (or cat the resultant files) if they're not completely clear to you.

The awk script has two main sections.  Awk scripts consist of repetitions of `condition { commands }`.  In this case, we've got two of these sets.

The first set has a condition of **`NR==FNR`**.  This evaluates as "true" if the current record number that awk is processing (NR) is the same as the current record number in the current file.  Obviously, this only works for the FIRST file, because as of the first line in the second file, NR is 1 plus the line count of the first file.

Within this section, we `split()` the line according to its equals sign, and put the data into an array called `vars`.

The second set has a condition of **`$1 in vars`**, which evaluates to true if the first word of the current line exists as a subscript of the `vars` array.  I include this only as an example of what you can do with vars, since I don't know what you're trying to achieve with these variables.

Does this address your problem?  If not, we'll need to see some of your code to get an idea of how to fix it.

---

**UPDATE** per suggestion in comments, here's proof that it works for large variables:

First, we prepare our input data:

```
$ dd if=/dev/random of=out.rand count=128k bs=1k
131072+0 records in
131072+0 records out
134217728 bytes transferred in 3.265765 secs (41098404 bytes/sec)
$ b64encode -o out.b64 out.rand out.rand
$ ls -lh out.b64
-rw-r--r--  1 ghoti  wheel   172M Jul 17 01:08 out.b64
$ awk 'BEGIN{printf("foo=")} NR>1{printf("%s",$0)} END{print ""}' out.b64 > vars
$ ls -lh vars
-rw-r--r--  1 ghoti  wheel   170M Jul 17 01:10 vars
$ wc -l vars
       1 vars
$ cut -c1-30 vars
foo=orq0UgQJyUAcwJV0SenJrSHu3j
```

Okay, we've got a ~170MB variable on a single line.  Let's suck it into awk.

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{split($0,a,"=");vars[a[1]]=a[2];next} END{print length(vars["foo"]);print "foo=" substr(vars["foo"],0,26);}' out.var bar
178956971
foo=orq0UgQJyUAcwJV0SenJrSHu3j
```

We can see the size of the variable, and the first 26 characters match what we saw from shell.  Yup, it works.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reference .. I have given the code reference could u pls see to that

Comment: I have somhow understood the solution but I am yet to be clear with this could you please look at the code reference and could you please let me know your idea.. I have edited the question

Comment: +1.  I just tested this solution with a single variable that was 128MB (a base64-encoded corefile).  It seems like awk has no problem with large variables.

Comment: Thanks Graham, that's an excellent suggestion for an example.  I'll include something like that in the answer.